# PL/SQL: how to save resultset into CSV file

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, plsql

I want to save PL/SQL resultset into CSV file.
Let's say that I have some PL/SL code:

```
...
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

How can I save the output in the CSV format?
I found this [link](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:88212348059) that seems to be related, however I cannot figure out how to pass resultset to the function.

Comment: Plsql with MySQL?!? That's a very odd combination...

Comment: Assuming this is for Oracle PL/SQL, the link you sent should work.. You would need to wrap your `stmt` and the corresponding results in a cursor and when you loop thru the cursor results, you then write to the file using the `UTL_FILE` package, Alternatively you could pass the results to another procedure as shown at this [link](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2163013?tstart=0) in which you then loop thru the results and use the `UTL_FILE` package there

Comment: I understand that when you mention PL/SQL, you mean a language used in a stored routine, because its syntax indicates that use MySQL, right?. If you are using MySQL, you can use: [SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html).

Comment: @wchiquito. Right. Thanks.